# Pandas - Create a DF with all the values from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF similar to the below.
What I want to do is to take the SKUs from SKU1 and SKU2 and create a separate DF with all possible SKU values. It seems simple but I'm having some trouble.

**DF**

| SKU1 | SKU2 |
| --- | --- |
| 66FS | 6dhs |
| b87w | ssftv |
| yy5hf |  |
|  | y346d |

**Desired Output**

| All_SKUs |
| --- |
| 66FS |
| b87w |
| yy5hf |
| 6dhs |
| ssftv |
| y346d |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = df.stack().droplevel(1).to_frame(name='All_SKUs')
```

output:

```
  All_SKUs
0     66FS
0     6dhs
1     b87w
1    ssftv
2    yy5hf
3    y346d
```

Else, [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
out = df.melt(value_name='All_SKUs').dropna().drop(columns='variable')
```

output:

```
  All_SKUs
0     66FS
1     b87w
2    yy5hf
4     6dhs
5    ssftv
7    y346d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.Series(df1.dropna().T.to_numpy().flatten(),name="All_SKUs")
```

output:

```
  All_SKUs
0     66FS
1     b87w
2    yy5hf
4     6dhs
5    ssftv
7    y346d
```